# Named Parameters not being substituted in Pentaho Mongo Input Query Expression

Tags: mongodb, transformation, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have created a transformation in Pentaho Kettle where I am pulling some data from Mongo Collection, via Mongo Input, but the problem I am facing is I have created two named parameters in the same transformation and they are not being replaced in Mongo Query Expression Tab. Below is my mongo query expression:

```
{$and:[{'key1':{'$in':['${para1}']}},{'key2':{'$in':['${para2}']}}]}
```

Below are the two options I have tried from command line:

```
./pan.sh -file='/dir../pull_data.ktr' -param:para1=hello -param:para2=world -Level=Basic > /dir../etl.log

./pan.sh -file='/dir../pull_data.ktr' -param:"para1=hello" -param:"para2=world" -Level=Basic > /dir../etl.log
```

I am using Mac OSX and Pentaho Kettle (CE 5.2). Is it possible to use named parameters in the same transformation?

Comment: @Coeur: any suggestions?

Comment: No: I do not know anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `./pan.sh -file='/dir../pull_data.ktr' -listparam` to make sure you declared your parameters in the transformation settings.

Variable substitution inside of the JSON query should work AFAICS in the source code.

Comment: Yes, they are defined in the parameters tab. I already checked that. Do you think anything other things going wrong here?

Comment: The first commit on github for pentaho-mongodb-plugin was 2014-08-07 and has variable substitution already in place.  PDI-CE-5.2 was published 2014-10-06.  Can you check the timestamp of your plugin?  Else I'll have to inspect the ZIP file to see what version of the plugin was packaged.

Comment: it is 30th September,2014.

Comment: seems like mongodb plugin is removed from CE versions. check below commit 

https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/search?q=mongo&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93